# Conditionally add <script> element into header based on route

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with different routes, say *site.com/foo* and *site.com/bar*. I would like some widget scripts to be added to the html headers of the site only if the route is *site.com/foo* (and not if it is *site.com/bar*)

Currently what I have are a bunch of  elements in the header like this:

```
<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","xyz");</script>
```

so every child route of *site.com* gets the scripts.

Is there a way to conditionally add in these scripts based on routes using JS and HTML?

Comment: `console.log(window.location)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you somewhat looking for this? It's in plain javascript without any library

```
<html>
    <body onload="onloadFunc()">
    </body>

    <script>
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        function onloadFunc() {
            let path = window.location.pathname
            if(path.search("bar") >= 0){
                script.src = "a.js";
            } else{
                script.src = "b.js";
            }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(script);

    </script>
</html>
```